# falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin - Cors en ionic

Tags: php, angular, ionic, cors

Estoy haciendo una app con ionic y trato de conectra la API de mi sistema a la aplicacion pero me suelta este problema de CORS

> Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en http://clinicasbv.byethost7.com/Api_login?correo=correo&clave=clave(razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin').

En la consola del navegador. He configurado el backend poniendo estas cabeceras

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Pero la verdad no tengo idea de porque tengo problemas de cors.

> estoy usando Byethost como hosting para probar el prototipo

Este es mi codigo del service.ts en la aplicacion de Ionic

```
    getUser(correo, password)
  {
    return this.http.get<any>('http://clinicasbv.byethost7.com/Api_login?correo='+ correo +'&clave='+ password);
  }
```

Basicamente necesito resolver los infinitos problemas de CORS para que todo funcione bien.

Comment: Esto es una configuración de backend, no se como sea en PHP pero en java los metodos deben estar configurados para aceptar peticiones de cualquier origen. `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` esto tambien se configura desde código.

Comment: Añadir el permiso de Cors al navegador *Estoy utilizando Google Chrome* [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/takvK.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/takvK.jpg)